# Ruby on Rails 3: after destroy method to destroy object if there is no more related objects in the system? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a little problem, i have the following 2 models:

```
class CriticalProcess < ActiveRecord::Base



  has_many :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, :through => :authorizations
  after_destroy :check_roles

  def check roles
     cp_roles = self.roles
     cp_roles.each do |role|
       if role.critical_processes.size == 0
          role.destroy
       end
     end
  end
end
```

and

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :authorizations
  has_many :critical_processes, :through => :authorizations

end
```

So 1 role can belong to many critical processes, is there any way I can make it that if **ALL** the critical processes that the role belonged to were to be destroyed, then for it to be destroyed as well? I need this because if all CP's (critical Processes) that the roles had a relationship with were to be destroyed then the role should also be destroyed as its no longer needed.

UPDATE

I have now created a after_destroy method which should delete the roles but this doesn't seem to be working, for some reason after debugging using the logs its not looping through the array for some reason?

why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe just brute-force it with a `before_destroy` filter in `CriticalProcess`. Tie that to a method that checks `self.roles` for any roles whose `critical_processes` list contains only `self` (the critical process that's about to be destroyed.

Comment: hi @jdl, how would i go about doing that check? can you show me what the method looks like please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probelm was that the autherization table was getting deleted before the self.roles was being called, so what i did was i changed the `after_destroy` to a `before_destroy` and made a couple more changes like so:

```
class CriticalProcess < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :authorizations
  has_many :roles, :through => :authorizations
  before_destroy :check_roles

  def check roles
     cp_roles = self.roles
     cp_roles.each do |role|
       if role.critical_processes.size == 1
          role.destroy
       end
       self.authorizations.each {|x| x.destroy}
     end
  end
end
```

Not the prtiest answer but it works, if anyone has a better answer please share it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could define the `after_destroy` [callback](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in the CriticalProcess class. Inside the `after_destroy` you could then check if the associated Role has zero CP's, and if so, delete the Role.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the answer, can you show me what the method to do this would look like? i tried somthing my self but couldnt get it working.

Comment: I tried this but its not working: 
``def role_check
    roles = self.roles
    roles.each do |role|
      if role.critical_processes.size == 0
        role.destroy
      end
    end
  end``