# Ruby on Rails: Better approach to delete related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, relationship

I have the following classes/relationships defined:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :component_stories,:dependent => :destroy
    has_many :stories, :through => :component_stories
end

class Story < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :component_stories,:dependent => :destroy
    has_many :components, :through => :component_stories
end

class ComponentStory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :component
    belongs_to :story
end
```

Let's say we have component1 with 2 stories: story1 and story2. story2 also belongs to component2. If we delete component1, story1 will be permanently removed, but story2 remains as it belongs to component2. I defined a method in the Component model to delete stories not related with any other component:

```
def delete_dependent_stories
   stories.each do |story|
     if story.component_stories.size == 1
       story.destroy
     end
   end
end
```

This method will be called in the destroy action for the components_controller:

```
def destroy
   component = Component.find(params[:id])
   component.delete_dependent_stories
   component.destroy
   ...
end
```

This way, I make sure there are no "zombie" stories not related to any component. My concern is if there could be a better approach that substitutes that method in the Component model.

Comment: looks fine - i would just move the delete_dependent_stories method to a before_destroy callback in the Component model

Comment: `if story.component_stories.size == 1
       story.destroy
end` will not work correctly in concurrent environment. Consider situation when we have story with two components c1 and c2, and two users delete these components simultaneously. `if` statement returns false in this case (because `story.component_storues.size` is actually equal to 2), no one removes that story, and - voilà - you've got a zombie.

Comment: BTW, similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546001/ruby-on-rails-3-after-destroy-method-to-destroy-object-if-there-is-no-more-rela

Comment: wrap it in a transaction

Comment: An after_destroy callback would be better than a before_destroy, as then you're guaranteed it will only happen once the first object *has* been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of model callbacks like this:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :component_stories,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :stories, :through => :component_stories

  after_destroy :delete_dependent_story?

  private

  def delete_dependent_stories
    stories.each do |story|
      if story.has_component_stories?
        story.destroy
      end
  end
end

class Story < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :component_stories,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :components, :through => :component_stories

  self.has_component_story?
    component_stories.size == 1
  end
end
```

Do not use `before_destroy` as it would remove `story` regardless of success of deletion of the `component`.