# Rails/ActiveRecord dependent destroy loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In Rails 3.2.x, the following worked fine:

```
class Engine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car, dependent: :destroy
end
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engine, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :owner
end
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I call `owner.destroy`, it would delete that owner, its car and that car's engine. I upgraded to Rails 4 and unfortunately I get an endless loop between engine and car. I assume because when the car is trying to be deleted, Rails first deletes its engine. Then when trying to delete the engine Rails first tries to delete its car..

How do I deal with this in Rails 4? I want to be able to delete an owner and Rails/ActiveRecord automatically deletes the associated car and engine. Or I can delete an engine and Rails automatically deletes the associated car, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `inverse_of` instead `dependent`

```
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to
```

This may help you.

Comment: If I use `inverse_of` instead of `dependent`, Rails knows to delete the associated models?

Comment: Nope :(, doesn't work... But looks like I should be using `inverse_of` in general.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `inverse_of` and `dependent: :destroy` doesn't work either :(. It seems like Rails 4/ActiveRecord should be smart enough, especially with `inverse_of` to detect there's a loop going on..

Comment: Try this one [inverse_of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5559737/3170288](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5559737/3170288)
[http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_destroy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_destroy)

Comment: I don't know a way those help

Comment: You should create a `callback` and then in this call back you can destroy other dependent objects.